# Edit a file without going over the whole bytes buffer?

Tags: java, android, file, file-io

I want to "override" or "switch" some bytes (say the first 2048 bytes from the file) with another bytes array, in a file which size is 100MB.
I don't want to read the whole file, because it takes a critic time for me to go over the whole file.

What I've tried so far:

```
FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);

out.getChannel().write(buffer, position);
```

The new buffer array is in the same size.

I'm developing with java + eclipse Android application which need to to that.
I'll be glad if someone could write me a piece of code that do the job.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: We're not going to write code for you, but will try to help fix whatever you've tried so far.

Comment: @Marc B: thanks, I've added it to the question's body

Comment: @Bhavik Ambani: are you sure?  if it's possible with c, why not with Java??

Comment: Are you talking about overwriting the first 2048 bytes with exactly 2048 new bytes or with an arbitrarily sized array?

Comment: what about writing somehow a native function, and to use it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This *overwrites* the first 2048 bytes of the file with the contents of the `data` array.

```
final RandomAccessFile file = new RandomAccessFile(filename, "rw");
final FileChannel channel = file.getChannel();
final byte[] data = new byte[2048];          // lets say it's got the data you want
final ByteBuffer buff = ByteBuffer.wrap(data);

channel.position(0);                         // (we were already here, but as an example)
channel.write(buff);                         // writes the entire 2028 bytes from buff
channel.force(false);                        // (superfluous if you close() afterwards)
channel.close();                             // close the file descriptor
```

Comment: @TalKanel:  I'm not sure I've done anything different to what you seem to be doing - but this is how to do it ...

Comment: basically the solution you provided me is working,  but now my problem is that it seems like assess to files I've just modified (swiping the first bytes) is sometimes been denying. only after a cuple of seconds passes - I can use the modified file.    any idea what I can do about it? (beside waiting some time before using the file).  maybe the files are not been closed properly?   thanks.

Comment: @TalKanel: this seems like a good candidate for a new SO question - that way you can provide enough details and error messages ...